# How two play a two flash swf files on two monitor?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air

I have two swf files and two monitors.  the first swf play on first monitor and the second swf play on second monitor.  How can i do this on flash or any plugin ? how can i find the connected screens pls help any one?

Answer (score 1):

See [Display screens in AIR](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a47e0-8000.html) for explanation and documentation for [Screen](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/display/Screen.html) class.
All screens form one virtual desktop, so window coordinates will determine on which screen it would appear.